# Getting error message even after setting safe=False

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django. I have following list of dictionaries -

```
userList = [{'value': '1', 'time': '2020-11-30T04:48:57.642Z'}]
```

I want to use it in Json Response as follows -

```
data = {
        'status': 'success',
        'message': userList
        }
```

For that I did the following -

```
return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Still I am getting error as -

```
In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong or what should I do to achieve the aim?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried restarting your django server?

Comment: @at-in yes I tried but it is not working

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure why you are getting this error, If you have a hosted repo for your code, please add a link, I'll be happy to help you :)

Comment: Did you check other `return JsonResponse` statements? maybe you forgot to add `safe=False` somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because i was using `json.dumps` on the input of `JsonResponse`
before.
You need to give the real dict into `JsonResponse` instead of a string representation.